# Open Street Maps new MapPath creates one big area rather than a number of smallers. How to get two areas?

Tags: c#, uwp, openstreetmap

I have to show on the map a number of areas, which are generated by the user in program. I can easily create one area, but when trying to add the second one, it connects with the previous one, creating the one big are. How can I obtain a number of areas, which do not connect with each other? There is how I do try to add the "static" area basing on user input of coordinates:
EDIT:
I do use this controler: [UniversalMapControl](https://github.com/mjeanrichard/UniversalMapControl)

```
mapView.Children.Add(new UniversalMapControl.Controls.MapPath
        {
            Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
            StrokeThickness = 2,
            IsFilled = true,
            IsClosed = true,
            Opacity = 0.5,
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.AliceBlue),

            PathItems = { Coordinates[0], Coordinates[1], Coordinates[2] }
        });
```

Some screenshots presenting the problem:

1.Generating the first area:
[image: First area]

2. Creating static image of first area:
   [image: Static first area]
3. Generating second area:
   [image: Second Area]
4. Badly creation of the static second area:
   [image: Connected areas]

Comment: Please mention the library you are using.

Comment: I've just updated the question with the link to the controler. Thanks!